# Making VBA script to map Excel fields to Project more efficient

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

So I have Microsoft Project file with around 600 rows of parent tasks. I need to import new data from Excel into this Project file using the Import Wizard and then run a script that creates four milestones below each parent task and then maps date and text fields from the Excel file into the correct cells in the Project file. If the parent task already has four milestones (and is not a new parent task) then the script updates the date and text fields for the task with the new data. I used the following script to accomplish this, and it works. However, it takes over 10 minutes to run. I know this is not the most efficient way to write this script. Can anyone help me modify the script so it takes less time to run?

```
Sub InsertSubTask()

    Dim tsk As Task
    For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks
        If tsk.Flag1 And tsk.OutlineChildren.Count = 0 Then
            With ActiveProject
                tsk.Name = tsk.Text5 + " " + "-" + tsk.Name
                .Tasks.Add tsk.Name + " " + "-" + " " + "Milestone 1", tsk.ID + 1
                .Tasks.Add tsk.Name + " " + "-" + " " + "Milestone 2", tsk.ID + 2
                .Tasks.Add tsk.Name + " " + "-" + " " + "Milestone3", tsk.ID + 3
                .Tasks.Add tsk.Name + " " + "-" + " " + "Milestone4", tsk.ID + 4
                
                .Tasks(tsk.ID + 1).OutlineIndent
                .Tasks(tsk.ID + 2).OutlineIndent
                .Tasks(tsk.ID + 3).OutlineIndent
                .Tasks(tsk.ID + 4).OutlineIndent
                
                .Tasks(tsk.ID + 1).Start = DateAdd("d", -1, tsk.Date4)
                .Tasks(tsk.ID + 2).Start = tsk.Date2
                .Tasks(tsk.ID + 3).Start = tsk.Date4
                .Tasks(tsk.ID + 4).Start = tsk.Date3
         
                tsk.Text10 = "Example"
                .Tasks(tsk.ID + 1).Text10 = "Example"
                .Tasks(tsk.ID + 2).Text10 = "Example"
                .Tasks(tsk.ID + 3).Text10 = "Example"
                .Tasks(tsk.ID + 4).Text10 = "Example"
                
                tsk.Text18 = "MILESTONE"
                .Tasks(tsk.ID + 2).Text18 = "MILESTONE"
                
                .Tasks(tsk.ID + 1).BaselineStart = tsk.Date5
                .Tasks(tsk.ID + 2).BaselineStart = tsk.Date2
                .Tasks(tsk.ID + 3).BaselineStart = tsk.Date4
                .Tasks(tsk.ID + 4).BaselineFinish = tsk.Date3
                .Tasks(tsk.ID + 2).ActualFinish = tsk.Date7
                
                          
                
            End With
        End If
        
        Next tsk

    For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks
            If tsk.Flag1 And tsk.OutlineChildren.Count = 4 Then
                With ActiveProject
                    
                    .Tasks(tsk.ID + 1).Start = DateAdd("d", -1, tsk.Date4)
                    .Tasks(tsk.ID + 2).Start = tsk.Date2
                    .Tasks(tsk.ID + 3).Start = tsk.Date4
                    .Tasks(tsk.ID + 4).Start = tsk.Date3
                    
                    
                    .Tasks(tsk.ID + 1).BaselineStart = tsk.Date5
                    .Tasks(tsk.ID + 2).BaselineStart = tsk.Date2
                    .Tasks(tsk.ID + 3).BaselineStart = tsk.Date4
                    .Tasks(tsk.ID + 4).BaselineFinish = tsk.Date3
                    .Tasks(tsk.ID + 2).ActualFinish = tsk.Date7
                    
                    
                End With
            End If
            
            Next tsk
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Likely better on the Code Review Stack.

Comment: Which part is slow--the Import Wizard or this macro? If it's the wizard, post a sample of the data that is being merged in.

Comment: No the wizard is fast. It's the macro.